# Is a level set more than one level curve?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, gradient-flows

What prompts me to ask this is i am trying to prove the gradient is perpendicular to the level set.   I am using  w = x^2 + y^2 .  When I graph this I get a cup shaped figure in three dimensions and when I graph the level sets they are circles since w is a constant.  Is this true so far ??

So now if we follow a path through the level sets is the path on ONE circle or a set of circles?  That is where my confusion lies.   Then I believe the rest of the proof shows the dot product of the gradient with the velocity vector is o!

But is the gradient perpendicular to each level curve were w = some constant? If so then there would be a gradient for each point of the path through the level sets IF the level set contains more than one level curve?  A little nomenclature confusion on my part.   Perhaps it is a set of a bunch of circles and the gradient is perpendicular to each constant value of w? If you could use my example it would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

A figure worth a thousand words.

Considering the change of variables

$$
x = r \cos\theta\\
y = r \sin\theta\\
z = r^2
$$

The level lines $\phi(r_0,\theta) = \{r_0\cos\theta,r_0\sin\theta,r_0^2\}$ and the lines $\psi(r,\theta_0)=\{r\cos\theta_0,r\sin\theta_0, r^2\}$  at point $\left(r_0,\theta_0\right)$  are orthogonal because

$$
< \frac{d\phi}{d\theta}, \frac{d\psi}{dr} > = 0
$$

[image]

Comment: almost..  nice sketch ...now sketch the path of r(t) along the level sets to show perpendicularity.  Does the path go up down or left right....that is the essence of the question....does the path follow  multiple circles in an up down pattern or one circle in a left to right pattern,....if you are confused what r(t) is ...it's the ubiquitous proof every calculus book on earth uses to prove that the gradient is perpendicular to the level curve ...thank you

Comment: I hope it is OK now.

Comment: thank you    the last line didn't translate but that's ok I think I can figure it out